# Yii CDbHttpSession, where is it called?

Tags: php, session, yii

I've been trying to locate where the CDbHttpSession is called after login, to rewrite it.

My problem is that I have 3 products in my App, and each are restricted on X simultaneous users, so I shouldn't allow any user to access these products until someone closes session or the admin manually removes the session from the DB.

Any help on how could I achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to regulate concurrent access with any amount of precision, sessions are not going to cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fixed application component available from [`CWebApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication). So you can access the session instance through [`Yii::app()->session`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#session-detail). You can configure your own session component in your `main.php`.

```
'components' => array(
    'session' => array(
        'class' => 'MyCustomSession',
    ),
),
```

But this is probably not the right place where you want to solve your problem. There is no "close session" event in PHP's session system. So you can not really find out, when a user has "closed" his session.

What could be helpful for you are maybe the [`afterLogin()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#afterLogin-detail) and [`afterLogout()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#afterLogout-detail) methods in [`CWebUser`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser). Much like with the `session` component you can also override the `user` component with your own class. There you can at least get hold of every login/logout process and do something. Note though, that a log out does not necessarily always occur: The session can simply time out and you won't get hold if it.